# Accessing a Java class property in a JS File

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am a new Bee in javascript. I am trying to work around accessing a java property that is present in a .java class in a javascript file. A Sample example would be:

```
/******************************JAVA **************************/ 

 public class SampleProgram {

   public String input = "Hello"
 }
```

/***************************************JS ************************/

```
 <script>

 window.setObject("inputValue", new SampleProgram().input);
 console.loh(window.getObject("inputValue"));
```

PS: I know this is acheivable through JSP's .However, I want to figure out an alternative way.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thankyou!

Comment: Indeed  a good question.

Comment: Generally, you would set a variable in the HTML template, something like `<script>var property = ${foo}</script>` or `<input type="hidden" value="${foo}">` (modify for your templating language).

Comment: Java and JS are not related at all. the Similarities in name have just been a marketing gag/strategy when JS was introduced. The Problem is: JS runs in the browser (on the clients computer), Java does not. So one way is to generate some piece of JS in Java and inject that into the output. Another way is to use ajax to call a server that runs Java and returns the value you requested. These are your options. There's no way to mix these two languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really mix languages this way.  Separate the browser logic from the server logic and exchange data through HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to directly expose the methods or properties of a java class to JavaScript.

Java sever pages do let you access javabean properties in a server side templating context, but giving JavaScript access requires ugly hacks where you mix jsp tags in with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var variableFromServer = '{someBean.someProperty}';
 </script>
```

If you aren't using jsp, you'll need to expose your java code using some other technique like JAX-RS, which is used to build http based api.

Comment: To build on Robert's answer above I have used JSF quite a lot and embedded JS tags to call Java bean properties into JS var parameters using var varname = '#{someBean.someProperty}'. Have also tried this with JSON type data